# Default font in Eclipse on OSX is terrible (and blurred)

Tags: eclipse, macos

Removing

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

from eclipse.ini and changing the font to menlo seems to improve the situation a bit. However the font is still a bit unsharp, compared to Xcode.

I don't see why they ship it like that or do they just don't care about the mac version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What version of OSX and of Eclipse are you using?

- Menlo is a [Snow Leopard font](http://rubenerd.com/snow-leopard-menlo/)
- [SWT has a Cocoa port in Eclipse 3.5](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/cocoaport.php)

smallFonts were fixed for [SWT Cocoa only in 3.5](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=225266).

(picture of font menlo in action)
[image: http://rubenerd.com/uploads/screenie.snowleopard.menlo.png]

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20
```

Comment: Version: The newest. I just clicked on it on the eclipse page.. It's eclipse-cocoa I think.

Comment: Monaco cursive is just not usable.

Comment: @Nils, regarding Monaco cursive broken in Galileo, I have updated my answer with a thread which mentions the issue and propose a solution.

Comment: I used: defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20 -- 9 is too low.

Comment: @sprugman: right on. This is the only command you need. the other one turns off antialiasing for the whole system

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe: good point. I have include spugman's comment and yours to the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

The workaround I found on this page https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382972#c4 works perfect for me:

Do "Show package contents" on the Eclipse.app.  Edit Contents/Info.plist.  Just above

```
</dict>
</plist>
```

Place this:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

Then, log out or make a copy of the app so that OSX will notice the change.  Now, the info window will not show "Open in Low Resolution" as checked.  Launch Eclipse and enjoy your new retina awesomeness.

Comment: Note: Logging out and back in did not work for me.  I had to copy the app.  Also, if open the Info.plist in xcode, you can just add the NSHighResolutionCapable easily.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying [Anonymous Pro](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymouspro.html), it's a free monospaced font, works very well for me. Read more [here](http://hivelogic.com/articles/anonymous-pro-programming-monospace-font).

There's also Consolas, from Microsoft, which is very good. More details on how to get it on a Mac can be found [here](http://www.wezm.net/2009/03/install-consolas-mac-osx/).

Answer (score 0):

I was battling with this issue today and it is also applicable to other applications such as jEdit (yet to verify).
I had eclipse working perfectly fine by itself, ADT, FlashBuilder 4.7 but not in FlashBuilder 4.6.

Indeed adding NSHighResolutionCapable, per comment #5 fixed it.
Logging out, even reboot, did not make a difference.
But copying, deleting the original and renaming the app did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Consolas 13pt on Kepler OSX and no issue.

[image]

Comment: Does not look sharp on my screen, but it's probably the picture. Also check the date of the question. Things might changed.

Comment: I can see much difference when I move from Juno to Eclipse Kepler version. I am not sure which version did you use then ?

Comment: Ok haven't used it for a while.

Answer (score -2):

[Xcode http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/176b770a89.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/176b770a89.png)

[eclipse http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c141361de2.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c141361de2.png)

Humm I still think Xcode looks a bit better, but this is probably also because of the smaller font.

Comment: Not sure what your trying to share here? I'm guessing you tried one of the suggested answers and this is the result? I think that info (which is definitely useful) is better placed as a comment on that answer or as an addition to your original question.